# A "pointless" animation program

Tags: java, object-oriented, homework, animation, javafx

The assignment description for this code is this:

> Each time the user clicks the Circles button, randomly colored circles
>   flow into the display and continuously change their shapes.

Here is a screenshot of my program running:

[image]

This is my first time seriously exploring the aspects of Java 8 development.  Therefore, I would like reviews to be tailored as such, since I would like to know the best way for using it in the future.

---

```
package java8;

import java.util.stream.Stream;
import javafx.animation.ScaleTransition;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 * A lab exercise to introduce Java 8 streams and JavaFX
 * @author syb0rg
 */
public class Java8 extends Application {

    public static final int ROWS = 4;
    public static final int COLS = 5;
    public static final int CELL_SIZE = 100;
    public static final int RADIUS = 25;

    /**
     * This method kicks off the initialization process.
     * @param primaryStage the main frame
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        root = new VBox();
        canvas = new Pane();
        starter = new Button("Circles");

        configure();
        addButtonHandler();

        root.getChildren().addAll(canvas, starter);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Java 8 Lab Exercise");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * This method sets the alignment of the root container
     * and the size of the canvas.
     */
    private void configure() {
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        canvas.setPrefSize(COLS*CELL_SIZE, ROWS*CELL_SIZE);
    }

    /**
     * This method adds the handler to the button that gives
     * this application its behavior.
     */
    private void addButtonHandler() {
        starter.setOnAction(e -> {
            circles();
        });
    }

    /**
     * This method creates a column of circles using Streams.
     */
    private void circles() {
        canvas.getChildren().clear();
        Stream<Stream<Circle>> circles = Stream.generate(() -> this.makeRow()).limit(ROWS);
        row = 0;
        circles.forEach(r -> {
            addRowToCanvas(r);
        });
    }

    /**
     * This method creates a row of circles using Streams.
     * @return Stream <Circle> the row of circles
     */
    private Stream <Circle> makeRow() {
        return Stream.generate(() -> new Circle(RADIUS)).limit(COLS);
    }

    /**
     * This method adds adds the row of circles to the canvas.
     * @param s the stream of circles to add to the canvas
     */
    private void addRowToCanvas(Stream <Circle> s) {
        column = 0;
        s.forEach(c -> {
            addToCanvas(c);
        });
        row++;
    }

    /**
     * This method adds a circle to a position on the canvas.
     * @param c the circle to add
     */
    private void addToCanvas(Circle c) {
        c.setFill((Paint) new Color(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1));
        double toX = column * CELL_SIZE + (CELL_SIZE/2);
        double toY = row * CELL_SIZE + (CELL_SIZE/2);
        double fromX = (COLS*CELL_SIZE) - (CELL_SIZE/2);
        double fromY = (ROWS*CELL_SIZE) - (CELL_SIZE/2);
        c.setCenterX(fromX);
        c.setCenterY(fromY);
        canvas.getChildren().add((Circle)c);
        column++;
        TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis((double)500));
        translate.setNode((Node)c);
        translate.setByX(toX - fromX);
        translate.setByY(toY - fromY);
        translate.play();
        ScaleTransition scale = new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis((double)(500 * Math.random() + 500)));
        scale.setNode((Node)c);
        scale.setByX(2);
        scale.setByY(2);
        scale.setCycleCount(-1);
        scale.setAutoReverse(true);
        scale.play();
    }

    private VBox root;
    private Pane canvas;
    private Button starter;
    private int row;
    private int column;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String... args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks very nice, straightforward code. A few minor improvements are possible.

#### Simplifications of lambdas

This uses a statement lambda:

> ```
> starter.setOnAction(e -> {
>     circles();
> });
> ```

... can be replaced with an expression lambda:

```
starter.setOnAction(e -> circles());
```

---

This uses an expression lambda:

> ```
> Stream<Stream<Circle>> circles = Stream.generate(() -> this.makeRow()).limit(ROWS);
> ```

... can be replaced with method reference:

```
Stream<Stream<Circle>> circles = Stream.generate(this::makeRow).limit(ROWS);
```

Similarly:

```
circles.forEach(r -> {
    addRowToCanvas(r);
});
```

Replace statement lambda with method reference:

```
circles.forEach(this::addRowToCanvas);
```

There are a few other places too where you can apply similar transformations.

#### Redundant casts

In `addToCanvas` you have several redundant casts, that can be simply dropped:

```
    c.setFill((Paint) new Color(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1));
    // ...
    canvas.getChildren().add((Circle) c);
    // ...
```

... and others.

#### Random numbers

Instead of `Math.random()`, it's better to use an instance of `Random` and its `nextDouble()` method. It's more modern, it can be seeded (for easier testing, for example), and passed as parameter, if ever needed.

#### Magic numbers

The number 500 appears at multiple places. If they are related, it would be good to put this into a constant.

#### Code organization

These variables are declared near the bottom of the cast:

> ```
> private VBox root;
> private Pane canvas;
> private Button starter;
> private int row;
> private int column;
> ```

The recommended practices is to declare all field variables at the top of the class.

Comment: When I do `Stream.generate(() -> new Circle(RADIUS))`, can I somehow make that into a method reference since I'm calling the constructor method?

Comment: @janos Any thoughts about comparing `Stream.generate(this::makeRow).limit(ROWS)` with `IntStream.range(0, ROWS).mapToObj(i -> this.makeRow())`?

Comment: @syb0rg if you called a parameterless constructor, you could write `Stream.generate(Circle::new)`. But you need the `RADIUS` parameter, so you need the lambda expression in this case.

Comment: @h.j.k. `Stream.generate(this::makeRow).limit(ROWS)` looks shorter and simpler. Is there a reason you would prefer the alternative you mentioned?

Comment: Not so much a preference... ;) Just that `limit(long)`'s Javadoc comes with a lengthy "API Note" explanation and itself is a form of stream operation to turn an infinite stream into a finite one, whereas the `IntStream` alternative defines a finite stream. Was wondering if such differences in definition (and likely implementation) matters or not...

Comment: @h.j.k. Excellent point to read the [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-)! Having read it *now*, `.limit` can be expensive on ordered parallel pipelines, but here we have an unordered stream source (`generate(Supplier)`), so it should be fine. A second part of your question seems to ask if it's better to create a finite stream in the first place, rather than infinite + convert to finite later. If the API docs doesn't express a concern (I cannot see), then we don't need to speculate. Correct me if I'm wrong, I'm no expert of streams!

Comment: @janos sounds about right... ;)